# How to extract table names from SQL queries?

Tags: regex, t-sql

I'm trying to extract table names from queries. This what I have for now:

```
(from|join)[\s|\t]*(((\ *(\[?)(?(5)(\ *[\w\-\_\d\$\ \#]+\]))|[\w\-\_\d\$\#]+)\.?){1,4})
```

It works fine with below example. I can receive what I want without extra selection (word bla)

```
from linkedserver.db.schema.table bla
from db.schema.table bla
from schema.table bla
from table bla
from [linked  dserver]. [  db  ].   [  schema].[table] bla
from [db].schema.  [table] bla
from [schema].  [table] bla
from [table  ] bla
```

Result is:

```
linkedserver.db.schema.table
db.schema.table
schema.table
table
[linked  dserver]. [  db  ].   [  schema].[table]
[db].schema.  [table]
[schema].  [table]
[table  ]
```

But it fails with below format where there is a  space between the object name and the dot:

```
from db.schema   .   table bla
from [db]  .   schema.  [table] bla
```

How to overcome it?

Comment: What language are you using? Regular expressions might not be the best tool here. An SQL parser could help more.

Comment: Even if someone gives you a regex which would work for the samples you gave, it could still fail on other untested data.  You might want to look into using a SQL parsing library of some kind.

Comment: I use powershell and now i'm playing with regex at https://regexr.com/.I understand that SQL parser is preferred  tool. Now i'm interested if i could solve this particular task with regex.

Comment: `[\t|\s]` does not do what you think; it matches a tab, or the character `|`, or whitespace (in some regex dialects). You are probably looking simply for `\s`, which is incidentally also the answer to your question (add another `\s*` where you want to permit optional whitespace).